# Is it possible to do a conditional concat?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that pulls different data but for one field it concats it, since the URL is partially filled in my database:

```
select blah, blah2, blah3, concat('https://my_url.com', g.logourl ) as logourl
```

but the problem is if logourl is blank then I just get https://my_url.com instead of the full URL. This is having down stream impact.

Is there a way to only concat if logurl is not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `case when` expression

```
select blah, blah2, blah3, 
 case when g.logourl is not null and g.logourl<>''
     then concat('https://my_url.com', g.logourl ) end as logourl
```

Comment: oddly this does not work. I get the results in the same way I got it above.

Comment: @Lostsoul, I've just added a condition which should solve your problem, I hope

Comment: Thank you Fahmi, it's still not working with the update. It's so strange. The column appears empty and I cannot see any special string in it

Comment: it worked when I removed your or statement  so it's this - case when  g.logourl<>''
     then concat('https://my_url.com', g.logourl ) end as logourl

Comment: @Lostsoul, that's great!

Comment: That "or" should be an "and": as currently written, an empty string passes the "is not null" test and the other test doesn't matter, because only one side of the "or" needs to be true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(case when g.logourl is not null  then 'https://my_url.com' || g.logourl 
 end) as logourl
```

If you want to avoid an empty string (and `NULL`) you can use:

```
(case when g.logourl <> ''  then 'https://my_url.com' || g.logourl 
 end) as logourl
```

If you want to eliminate a string of spaces:

```
(case when replace(g.logourl, ' ', '') <> ''  then 'https://my_url.com' || g.logourl 
 end) as logourl
```

Comment: oddly this does not work. I get the results in the same way I got it above.

Comment: @Lostsoul, could you please add some sample data of your table in the question?

Comment: @Fahmi I realized the problem, the data isn't null for this column oddly. it's just empty. In DBeaver I see some columns are [Null] but the empty columns for this specific column is just empty.

Comment: @Lostsoul, I've just added a condition which should solve your problem, I hope

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be `null` if `logurl` is null, then you can use the concat [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) `||` instead of the `concat()` function

```sql
select 'a' || null;
 ?column?
----------

(1 row)
```